# Find documents where certain field has exact same elements as object in MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an array of ids like so:

```
[5, 7, 9, 4, 18]
```

I have a collection with documents that are inserted with the following format:

```
db.collection('groups').insert(
  [
    {
      members: [
        {member: 5, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: true},
        {member: 7, hasSeen: true, requiresAction: true},
        {member: 4, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false}
      ]
    },
    {
      members: [
        {member: 5, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: true},
        {member: 4, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 7, hasSeen: true, requiresAction: true},
        {member: 9, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 18, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false}
      ]
    },
    {
      members: [
        {member: 7, hasSeen: true, requiresAction: true},
        {member: 9, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 4, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 18, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 1, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: false},
        {member: 5, hasSeen: false, requiresAction: true}
      ]
    }
  ]
);
```

I would like to find all documents in the collection "groups" that contain **only** the "member" ids in the above array, and order **shouldn't** matter. For example, if the search was conducted with the above array, **only** the second inserted document would be returned from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to employ the use of [MongoDB's aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) to find the required document(s).

The steps to be employed in the aggregation are listed below:

1. **Denormalize each of the documents by deconstructing the `members` array.**

   This can be achieved by using the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) 
   aggregation operator:

   > Deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element.

   The `$unwind` operator will split each document into several, each new document containing a `members` field that has a single member object:

   ```
   {_id: 'first_id', members: {member: 4, hasSeen: false}}
   {_id: 'first_id', members: {member: 5, hasSeen: fasee}}
   ```

   To use the `$unwind` operator, we'd simply add this to the aggregation pipeline:

   ```
   {$unwind: "$members"}
   ```
2. **Group the documents by their `_id` fields, adding the member ids to an array**

   This can be achieved by using the [$group](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation operator:

   > Groups documents by some specified expression and outputs to the next stage a document for each distinct grouping. The output documents contain an _id field which contains the distinct group by key. The output documents can also contain computed fields that hold the values of some accumulator expression grouped by the $group‘s _id field.

   The `$group` operator would allow us to group the denormalized documents by their ids while accumulating the member ids so we'll obtain documents of this form:

   ```
   {_id: 'first_id', member_ids: [5, 7, 4] }
   ```

   The expression required to group the documents and accumulate the ids is:

   ```
   {$group: { _id: "$_id", member_ids: { $push: "$members.member" } }}
   ```
3. **Filter the resulting documents according to the defined criteria**

   This can be achieved by using the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) aggregation operator:

   > Filters the documents to pass only the documents that match the specified condition(s) to the next pipeline stage.

   To obtain documents whose `member_ids` attribute matches the criteria, the expression is:

   ```
   {$match: {'member_ids': { $all: [5, 7, 9, 4, 18] } } }
   ```

The final aggregation query would be:

```
db.collection('groups').aggregate(
  [
    {$unwind: "$members"},
    {$group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      member_ids: { $push: "$members.member" }
    }},
    {$match: {'member_ids': { $all: [5, 7, 9, 4, 18] } } }
  ]
);
```